# Using a scalar as a condition in perl

Tags: perl, if-statement, conditional-statements, scalar

First timer...so let me know if there is anything that I have not paid attention to whilst posing a question.

The question is how to use a scalar as a condition, as the code below does not work.

```
my @parameter=('hub');

my %condition;
$condition{'hub'}{'1'}='$degree>=5';

foreach (@parameter) {
       if ($condition{$_}{'1'}) {..}
}
```

I thought that is because the condition is not interpreted correctly, so I also tried the following, which also did not work.

```
if ("$condition{$parameter}{'1'}") { ..}
```

Would really appreciate any help. :)

Comment: do you mean $condition{'hub'}{'1'} = '$degree => 5'; ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either want string eval, which evaluates a string as Perl code

```
if (eval $condition{$_}{'1'}) { ...
```

or perhaps a more secure approach would be using [code references](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlref#4)

```
$condition{'hub'}{'1'} = sub { return $degree>=5 };

if ($condition{$_}{'1'}->()) { ...
```

In the second example, you are attaching a piece of code to a variable. The `$var->()` syntax executes the code and evaluates to the return value of the code.

Comment: eval works.  $condition{'hub'}{'1'} = sub { return $degree>=5 }; does not work for me because the variables have to be defined for that to work -my variables are defined later in the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is to evaluate '$degree>=5' as real code.  Rather than trying to evaluate the string as code (which can be done with [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)), it's usually safer and often more robust to instead pass a code-reference.  You can use a generator subroutine to generate conditional subs on demand, like this:

```
sub generate_condition {
    my ( $test, $bound ) = @_;
    return sub { return $test >= $bound; };
}

my %condition;
$condition{'hub'}{'1'} = generate_condition( $degree, 5 );

if( $condition{$parameter}{1}->() ) { ... }
```

It gets a little more tricky if you want the `>=` (ie, the relationship itself) to be dynamically created as well.  Then you have a couple of choices.  One takes you back to stringy eval, with all of its risks (especially if you start letting your user specify the string).  The another would be a lookup table within your `generate_condition()` sub.

`generate_condition()` returns a subroutine reference that when invoked, will evaluate the condition that was bound in at creation time.

Here's a generalized solution that will accept any of Perl's conditionals and wrap them along with the arguments being tested into a subroutine.  The subref can then be invoked to evaluate the conditional:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/state/;

sub generate_condition {
    my ( $test, $relation, $bound ) = @_;
    die "Bad relationship\n" 
        if ! $relation =~ m/^(?:<=?|>=?|==|l[te]|g[te]|cmp)$/;
    state $relationships = {
        '<'     => sub { return $test <   $bound },
        '<='    => sub { return $test <=  $bound },
        '=='    => sub { return $test ==  $bound },
        '>='    => sub { return $test >=  $bound },
        '>'     => sub { return $test >   $bound },
        '<=>'   => sub { return $test <=> $bound },
        'lt'    => sub { return $test lt  $bound },
        'le'    => sub { return $test le  $bound },
        'eq'    => sub { return $test eq  $bound },
        'ge'    => sub { return $test ge  $bound },
        'gt'    => sub { return $test gt  $bound },
        'cmp'   => sub { return $test cmp $bound },
    };
    return $relationships->{$relation};
}


my $true_condition  = generate_condition( 10, '>', 5 );
my $false_condition = generate_condition( 'flower', 'eq', 'stamp' );

print '10 is greater than 5: ', 
      $true_condition->()  ? "true\n" : "false\n";
print '"flower" is equal to "stamp": ', 
      $false_condition->() ? "true\n" : "false\n";
```

Often when you construct these sorts of things one is interested in leaving one parameter open to bind at call-time rather than at subroutine manufacture-time.  Let's say you only want to bind the "`$bound`" and "$relation" parameters, but leave "`$test`" open for specification at subroutine call time.  You would modify your sub generation like this:

```
sub generate_condition {
    my ( $relation, $bound ) = @_;
    die "Bad relationship\n" 
        if ! $relation =~ m/^(?:<=?|>=?|==|l[te]|g[te]|cmp)$/;
    state $relationships = {
        '<'     => sub { return $_[0]  <   $bound },
        # ......
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
my $condition = generate_condition( '<', 5 );
if( $condition->(2) ) {
    print "Yes, 2 is less than 5\n";
}
```

If the goal is to provide late binding of both the lefthand and righthand side in the relational evaluation, this will work:

```
sub generate_condition {
    my $relation = shift;
    die "Bad relationship\n" 
        if ! $relation =~ m/^(?:<=?|>=?|==|l[te]|g[te]|cmp)$/;
    state $relationships = {
        '<'     => sub { return $_[0]  <   $_[1] },
        '<='    => sub { return $_[0]  <=  $_[1] },
        # ...... and so on .....
    return $relationship->($relation);
}

my $condition = generate_condition( '<' );
if( $condition->(2,10) ) { print "True.\n"; }
```

This sort of tool falls into the category of functional programming, and is covered in beautiful detail in Mark Jason Dominus's book [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)

Comment: Your first code block has problems: http://pastie.org/4515233 - should use \$degree / $$test.

Comment: You're just using it wrong.  It's not supposed to look at $degree after the sub is manufactured. It's intended to lock $degree and $test at the time that the condition sub is generated.  If you want to be able to update $degree you need to either generate a new sub (with new values bound in), or use the second code snippet that allows the trial value to remain free until such time that the anonymous sub is invoked.

Comment: Eh, okay, but that seems a little pointless - why evaluate the condition every time when the return value is constant?

Comment: The original post didn't specify at what point values should be bound.  The second snippet shows how to leave one parameter free.  If the OP wishes to leave both params free for late binding that's an easy alteration, and one that I may as well add as an update.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ...Ok, update added: Now the OP can choose to to bind "left, relation, right", or to leave "left" free, binding only "relation, right", or even to leave "left" and "right" free, binding only the relationship.  If he needs more flexibility than that, may as well eliminate the sub generator altogether and leave all three params free.

Comment: Thanks! Another victory for pedantry on the Internet! :)

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting? String values are interpreted as `true` when they are nonempty.

```
themel@kallisti: ~ $ perl -e 'print "oops\n" if "false" ; '
oops
themel@kallisti: ~ $ perl -e 'print "oops\n" if "" ; '
themel@kallisti: ~ $ perl -e 'print "oops\n" if "\$degree < 5" ;'
oops
```

If you want to dynamically evaluate code in your conditions, you have to investigate [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html). Example:

```
my @conds=('$foo>42', '$foo>23');
my $foo = 33;

foreach my $cond(@conds) { 
    print "$cond itself was true\n" if $cond;
    print "$cond evaluated to true\n" if eval($cond);
}
```

prints

```
$foo>42 itself was true
$foo>23 itself was true
$foo>23 evaluated to true
```

Comment: While a caution about `eval` is warranted, it is not always "the wrong way". Sometimes the fastest, easiest way is just fine.  Not every Perl script is going to be handling life support on the space station or guiding a robotic surgeon's scalpel.