# Multiple if statements formed from looping through an array

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

As you would see below is a bad perl practice of 'eval' a scalar containing code. That aside, in the following code, the condition '$condition{'b'}{'1'}' was not run through the loop. Only the condition that came first in the array ran, ie. condition '$condition{'a'}{'1'}', was run.

```
my @parameter=('a','b');

my %condition;
$condition{'a'}{'1'}='$degree>=5';
$condition{'b'}{'1'}='$number>5';

foreach (@parameter) {
   my $count=0;

   foreach (<INPUT>) {
   my $degree=....;  #$degree defined
   my $number=.....; #$number defined
   if (eval $condition{$_}{'1'}) {$count++}  #only $condition{'a'}{'1'} was run!
   }

}
```

The first question is why did the first condition got stuck in the loop and the second question is how can I fix it? Would really appreciate any help/advise/solutions. :)

Comment: The answer depends crucially on what that ".." is.

Comment: This question gives the impression that no progress was made after all the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11976045/716443  However, you should probably be testing `$@` to see if `eval` generated an error.  Otherwise, your problem exists within the unseen code contained within `{..}`.  And then go back and use one of the solutions that didn't require evaluating strings as code.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/11976045/716443 did help to get the condition working for the first element in the array, but then it got stuck.

Comment: Try this: `my $result = eval $condition{$_}{1};  die $@ if $@; if( $result ) { $count++ }`.  It won't magically fix the problem, but might prevent a silent failure from causing programmer confusion.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it did not make a difference. Returns $count=0 for the second in the array with no warning.

Comment: At the point of the `eval` `$_` contains the last line read from `INPUT`, not the current element of `@parameter`. Becuase you haven't used `chomp` it will include a newline and so won't match any of the hash keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach (@parameter)` loop runs its body for `'a'`. Within that loop the `foreach (<INPUT>)` loop consumes the input to its end.

The `foreach (@parameter)` loop then runs its body for `'b'`. Within that loop the `foreach (<INPUT>)` loop has no input because it has already been consumed.